# Can I get all contributions by users and export them in a csv file in MediaWiki?

Tags: export, mediawiki, csv, mediawiki-extensions

From my MediaWiki site, I would like to get all the contributions by users in the last month in a csv file format. Is there any extension for this? Can I query the database and get this information?

Answer (score 0):

You can query the database: http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help:Advanced_editing#Records_of_edits_in_the_database

> Edits are recorded both in the `revision` table and in the `recentchanges`
> table of the database.
>
> The revision table is used for page histories
> and user contribution lists.
> The recentchanges table is used for
> recent and related changes, watchlists, and (in the case of page
> creation) for the list of new pages.
>
> This distinction is relevant in
> the case that old edits are removed from one of the two tables. For
> example, if three months of recent changes are kept in the
> recentchanges table, while nothing is deleted from the revision table,
> then older edits can be seen in page histories and user contribution
> lists, but not in recent and related changes, watchlists, and (in the
> case of page creation) in the list of new pages.
>
> Import of page
> revisions adds to the revision table but not to the recentchanges
> table, so they add to page histories and user contribution lists, but
> not to recent and related changes, watchlists, and (in the case of
> page creation) the list of new pages.